# How can I access a other html file when the device width equals the width of a mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, responsive-design, width

So i have implemented you code with javascript but i still cant figure out how to do it. Ok Im noob in JS but yeah. 
here my code: 
First one is my index with CSS
second one is my "webapp" with CSS 
And I just doesnt want to work for some reason.
If I try to resize my browser it stays on the indes file.
So i have implemented you code with javascript but i still cant figure out how to do it. Ok Im noob in JS but yeah. 
here my code: 
First one is my index with CSS
second one is my "webapp" with CSS 
And I just doesnt want to work for some reason.
If I try to resize my browser it stays on the indes file.
So i have implemented you code with javascript but i still cant figure out how to do it. Ok Im noob in JS but yeah. 
here my code: 
First one is my index with CSS
second one is my "webapp" with CSS 
And I just doesnt want to work for some reason.
If I try to resize my browser it stays on the indes file.
So i have implemented you code with javascript but i still cant figure out how to do it. Ok Im noob in JS but yeah. 
here my code: 
First one is my index with CSS
second one is my "webapp" with CSS 
And I just doesnt want to work for some reason.
If I try to resize my browser it stays on the indes file.
So i have implemented you code with javascript but i still cant figure out how to do it. Ok Im noob in JS but yeah. 
here my code: 
First one is my index with CSS
second one is my "webapp" with CSS 
And I just doesnt want to work for some reason.
If I try to resize my browser it stays on the indes file.

```css
.fullscreen-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -100;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: center;
  width: 98%;
  height: 50%;
}

html {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin: 1%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 10px white, 0 0 40px black, 0 0 80px white;
  color: black;
  height: 96%;
  width: 98%;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
  float: center;
}

h1 {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 4px gray, 1px 1px 4px white;
}

p {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

header {
  padding: 1px;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px white, 0 0 20px white;
}

nav {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

article {
  float: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}


/*NAV Menu*/

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: black;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover,
.overlay a:focus {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

span {
  color: black;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 1%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 1%;
}


/*Responsive*/

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {
    font-size: 20px
  }
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}

footer {
  float: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 60%;
}

p1 {
  text-align: left;
}

.style {
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: monospace, arial;
}

span {
  color: black;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 1%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 1%;
}


/*LOGO*/

img.ri {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 80%;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

img.ri:empty {
  top: 55%;
  left: 49%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  html {
    background-image: url("C:/Users/Joalu/Desktop/WebApp/img/indexbackground.png");
    font-family: 'Lato';
    width: auto;
    height: 1908px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  header {
    text-align: center;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 3px;
    font-family: 'Lato';
  }
  h2 {
    display: block;
  }
  .btnheader {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border: 0;
    width: 485px;
    height: 87px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px white;
  }
  .overlay {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .btn-group button {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    /* Green background */
    border: 0.5px solid rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: white;
    /* White text */
    padding: 20px 33px;
    /* Some padding */
    cursor: pointer;
    /* Pointer/hand icon */
    float: left;
    /* Float the buttons side by side */
    font-family: 'Lato', arial;
    width: 120.7px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  /* Clear floats (clearfix hack) */
  .btn-group:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
  }
  .btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: none;
    /* Prevent double borders */
  }
  /* Add a background color on hover */
  .btn-group button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px black, 0 0 15px white;
  }
  .dot {
    height: 258px;
    width: 258px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 670px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .dot:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px white;
  }
  img.ri {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 80%;
    top: 20%;
    left: 10%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: 140px;
  }
  img.ri:empty {
    top: 35%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  img.ri:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray, 0 0 40px black;
  }
  .footer {
    padding: 5%;
    height: 464px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    margin-top: 320px;
    color: white;
  }
  h3 {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 380px;
  }
  .bordr {
    border: 5px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto
  }
  p {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Lato', arial;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/MainCSS.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="image/favicon.png" sizes="32x32">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>
    scxry
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="fullscreen-bg">
    <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg__video">
        <source src="video/12345.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
  <header>
    <span class="style" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>

  </header>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    if (screen.width <= 500) {
      document.location = "webapp.html";
    }
  </script>




  <nav>
    <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <div class="overlay-content">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="Store.html">Store</a>
        <a href="YouTube.html">Social Media</a>
        <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
        <a href="FAQ.html">FAQ</a>
        <p>scxry cmpny est. 2020
          <p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <img src="image/scxrylogo800back.png" class="ri" />


  <script>
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

    html{
        background-image: url("C:/Users/Joalu/Desktop/scxryshop.de/image/webappbackground.png");
        font-family:  'Lato';
        width: auto;
        height: 1908px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    body{
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    header{
        text-align: center;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 20px;
        color: white;
        margin-top: 3px;
        font-family:   'Lato';
    }

    h2 {
        display: block;

    }

    .btnheader {
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0,0.5);
        border: 0;
        width: 485px;
        height: 87px;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        box-shadow: 0 0 30px white;
    }

    .overlay {
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0,0.5);
        margin-top: 30px ;
        text-align: center;
    }


    .btn-group button {
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0,0.5); /* Green background */
        border: 0.5px solid rgb(0, 0, 0,0.5);
        color: white; /* White text */
        padding: 20px 33px; /* Some padding */
        cursor: pointer; /* Pointer/hand icon */
        float: left;/* Float the buttons side by side */
        font-family:  'Lato', arial;
        width: 120.7px;
        text-align: center;
        
      }
      
      /* Clear floats (clearfix hack) */
      .btn-group:after {
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        display: table;
      }
      
      .btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
        border-right: none; /* Prevent double borders */
      }
      
      /* Add a background color on hover */
      .btn-group button:hover {
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0,0.3);
        border: 0px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 40px black, 0 0 15px white;
      }
      
      .dot {
        height: 258px;
        width: 258px;
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0,0);
        border-radius: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 670px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .dot:hover {
          box-shadow: 0 0 50px white;
      }

      img.ri{
        position: absolute;
        max-width: 80%;
        top: 20%;
        left: 10%;
        border-radius: 3px;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        margin-top: 140px;
    }
    
    img.ri:empty{
        top: 35%;
        left: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
    img.ri:hover{
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray, 0 0 40px black;
    }

    .footer {
            padding: 5%;
            height: 464px;
            width: 500px;
            background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0,0.8);
            margin-top: 320px;
            color: white;
    }

    h3 {
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        margin-top: 380px;
    }

    .bordr {
        border: 5px;
        height: auto;
        width: auto
    }

    p {
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Lato', arial;
    }
    
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px) {



                



}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="css/webappcss.css" type="text/CSS" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  
</head>
<body>
    <header>

    <a href="https://www.scxryshop.de/">
        <button class="btnheader">
                <h1>scxry</h1>
        </button>
    </a>

    </header>
    <body>

      <div class="btn-group">
        <a href="https://www.scxryshop.de/">
            <button class="btn1">Media</button>
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.scxryshop.de/About.html">
            <button class="btn2">FAQ</button>
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.scxryshop.de/Contact.html">
            <button class="btn3">Contact</button>
        </a>
            <button class="btn4">About</button>
    </div>

    <a href="index.html">           <img src="image/custom.png" class="ri" style="height: auto"> </a>

        <div style="text-align:center">
            <a href="https://www.scxryshop.de/">
            <span class="dot"></span>
        </a>
        
          </div>
          <h3>Blog</h3>
          <div class="bordr">
              <p>This new mobile update will provide you <br> with the
            best experience.<br> Be sure to explore the whole website,<br>
            some personal information about me:</p>
            <p>I'm 15 years old and I'm a student at JKR Wendlingen <br>
            I will finish my school soon and will then go <br>
        to the MES in Kirchheim.</p>
        <p>I was thinking of selling some 3D printed <br>
        products because you can almost make everything <br>
    therefor prototyping is no problem.</p>
    <p>Also I'm looking forward to study abroad <br> and go to the 
        US. Thank you so much for visting <br>
        this website if you need any help <br>
        feel free to contact me.
    </p>
    <p><b>THANK YOU!</b></p>
          </div>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            if (screen.width >=  500) {
            document.location = "index.html";
            } 
            </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead on the main page you can use javascript to redirect the user

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if (screen.width <= 500) {
    document.location = "other.html";
    } else {
document.location = "index.html";
}
    </script>
```

Comment: Is not working idk why if  I use your code I resize the window and it shows the same css as before

Comment: @scxry i made some adjustments

Answer (score 0):

There are various elements and techniques to responsive design (changing content and/or layout across different device widths). Try not to think about it as a different HTML page but elements on the same page that show and hide according to the device width.

For example: -

```
<div class="desktop-content">
  <p>This is the content someone will see on a desktop</p>
</div>
<div class="mobile-content">
  <p>This is the mobile content</p>
</div>
```

And then with CSS you can then do something like this: -

```
.mobile-content{
  display:none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .desktop-content{
    display:none
  }
  .mobile-content{
    display:block;
  }
}
```

The disadvantage here is that you are asking the browser to load both sets of content but only displaying one so if there are large images or a lot of content involved another approach may be better.

If you MUST have 2 separate HTML files then you can do a JavaScript redirect based on the width of the window to the correct one ... but I would not recommend this approach.